# Why can't I initialize a final class variable via a closure inside the constructor in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, constructor, initialization, final

Can any one explain to me why the below code works if `final` is commented out, but not if `final` is present?

```
public class Person {
    public /*final*/ String firstName, lastName

    Person(Map parameters) {
        // This does *not* work with "final":
        parameters.each { name, value ->
            this."$name" = value
        }

        // This *does* work with "final":
        this.lastName = parameters['lastName']
    }
}

Person p = new Person(firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Doe')
println p.firstName + ' ' + p.lastName
```

In other words, why is it a difference whether I initialize the final variable inside a closure, or at the top-level of the constructor?

Comment: Not answering the question, but this should get a similar result? `@groovy.transform.Immutable public class Person { String firstName, lastName }`

Comment: Very nice, `Immutable` even already [provides a map-based constructor](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Immutable.html) like the one I'm implementing manually here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can any one explain to me why the below code works if final is
>   commented out, but not if final is present?

The compiler has to enforce that your final properties are initialized in the constructor and there is no way to do that in your example because the compiler doesn't know what will be in the `Map`.

Comment: If that was correct, why does it work then if I make the class `Immutable` and use the automatically provided map constructor? In that case the properties are final, too, and the compiler also cannot know what I'm providing n the map. I just tried it, and if I omit some property form the map no error occurs, it simply is `null` then.

Comment: @sschuberth "If that was correct, why does it work then if I make the class Immutable" - it works because when the class is marked `@Immutable` the compiler adds something that is effectively like `this.firstName = args.get('firstName')` to the constructor so the compiler can guarantee that `firstName` is a assigned a value. `null` is a valid value.

Comment: Mark the class with both `@Immutable` and `@CompileStatic` and decompile it.  You will see something like https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/8794211e48e39f1e20b5.  The `@CompileStatic` isn't really necessary, but the decompiled code will make more sense if you aren't familiar with Groovy internals.

Comment: Notice that every path through that code leads to a value being assigned to `this.firstName`.  That is what the compiler has to ensure for a `final` field.